# Как передать в WP Query несколько параметров для новых фильтрации?

Tags: wordpress

Добрый день есть стандартный цилк вывода постов в index.php
Использую ACF pro в котором передал возможность выбора сложности статьи( Для фильтрации и 3 варианта, через select custom field )
Вопрос, каким образом в параметры массива можно передать значения полей что бы выводить именно посты что имеют выбранный вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение полей можно передавать просто в параметр ''meta_query'

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'field1',
            'value'     => 'value1',
            'compare'   => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'field2',
            'value'     => 'value2',
            'compare'   => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'field3',
            'value'     => 'value3',
            'compare'   => '='
        )
    )
);


// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```